# Google Maps API v2 で3D表示ができない

Tags: android, google-maps

AndroidでGoogle Maps API v2を用いたアプリを作成しております．
マップの表示やマーカーの設定などは正常にできておりますが，ズームしたときに3Dの建物が
表示されず困っています．端末はNexus5,Androidのバージョンは5.0.1です．以下がマップの設定です．

```
private void mapInit() {
        isMapInit = true;
        //LocationManagerの取得
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //GPSから現在地の情報を取得
        Location myLocate = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
        // 地図タイプ設定
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        boolean test = googleMap.isBuildingsEnabled();

        // 現在位置ボタンの表示を行なう
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
        if(mLocationClient != null){
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }
}
```

試しにisBuildingsEnabled()の値を確認しましたが，trueになっておりました．
またGoogleMapでは3D表示ができているので，端末のバージョンなどは問題ないと思われます．
targetSdkVersionは21にしています．
ご教授よろしくお願い致します．

Answer (score 0):

日本で3D表示されないだけで、ロサンゼルス等では3D表示になっているのではないでしょうか。